# Makefile: how to run bash script and ignore its exit status?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Minimized test case for the problem:

I have following `Makefile`:

```
test:
    bash test.sh || true
    echo OK
```

and the `test.sh` contains

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -p "Enter some text or press Ctrl+C to exit > " input
do
    echo "Your input was: $input"
done
```

When I run `make test` and press Ctrl+C to exit the bash `read` the make will emit

```
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Interrupt
```

**How can I tell `make` to ignore the exit status of the script?** I already have  `|| true` after the script which usually is enough to get `make` to keep going but for some reason, the SIGINT interrupting the `read` will cause `make` to behave different for this case.

I'm looking for a generic answer that works for processes other than `while read` loop in `bash`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make this work. It's a bit tricky so I'll explain the solution first. The important thing to understand that Ctrl+C is handled by your *terminal* and not by the currently running process in the terminal as I previously thought. When the terminal catches your Ctrl+C it will check the *foreground process group* and then send `SIGINT` to *all* processes in that group immediately. When you run something via Makefile and press Ctrl+C the `SIGINT` be immediately sent to Makefile and all processes that it started because those all belong in the foreground process group. And GNU Make handles `SIGINT` by *waiting* for any currently executed child process to stop and then exit with a message

```
Makefile:<line number>: recipe for target '<target>' failed
make: *** [<target>] Interrupt
```

if the child exited with non-zero exit status. If child handled the `SIGINT` by itself and exited with status 0, GNU Make will exit silently. Many programs exit via status code 130 on `SIGINT` but this is not required. In addition, kernel and `wait()` C API interface can differentiate with status code 130 and status code 130 + child received `SIGINT` so if Make wanted to behave different for these cases, it would be possible regardless of exit code. `bash` doesn't support testing for child process `SIGINT` status but only supports exit status codes.

**The solution** is to setup processes so that your foreground process group does not include GNU Make while you want to handle Ctrl+C specially. However, as POSIX doesn't define a tool to create any process groups, we have to use `bash` specific trick: use bash job control to trigger `bash` to create a new process group. Be warned that this causes some side-effects (e.g. stdin and stdout behaves slightly different) but at least for my case it was good enough.

Here's how to do it:

I have following `Makefile` (as usual, nested lines must have TAB instead of spaces):

```
test:
    bash -c 'set -m; bash ./test.sh'
    echo OK
```

and the `test.sh` contains

```
#!/bin/bash
int_handler()
{
    printf "\nReceived SIGINT, quitting...\n" 1>&2
    exit 0
}
trap int_handler INT 

while read -p "Enter some text or press Ctrl+C to exit > " input
do
    echo "Your input was: $input"
done
```

The `set -m` triggers creating a new foreground process group and the `int_handler` takes care of returning successful exit code on exit. Of course, if you want to have some other exit code but zero on Ctrl+C, feel free to any any value suitable. If you want to have something shorter, the child script only needs `trap 'exit 0' INT` instead of separate function and setup for it.

For additional information:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99134/20336
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386856/20336
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479195/334451
- https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html

Comment: GNU/Linux has the `setsid` tool (`man 1 setsid`) which is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the exit status of the script.  When you press ^C you're sending an interrupt signal to the *make* program, not just to your script.  That causes the make program to stop, just like ^C always does.

There's no way to have make ignore ^C operations; whenever you press ^C at the terminal, make will stop.

Comment: Technically the Ctrl+C will be sent to the script, not to the `make` script. Additional testing shows that if I `trap` the SIGINT in `test.sh` I can *delay* the `SIGINT` as long as I want. However, even if `test.sh` later calls `exit 0` the final result is not returning from the shell with exit value 0 but SIGINT at that time. As a result, there seems to be no way to NOT have `make` to see SIGINT sooner or later.

Comment: The SIGINT is always sent to make immediately, as I said.  The effect you're seeing is because when make receives the signal, it doesn't exit immediately instead it waits for its child processes to die and cleans up after them, before exiting itself.  So if you delay the exit of your script, that will delay the exit of make as well.  But, make already got the signal and _will_ die.

Comment: I stand corrected. I found a good explanation of the whole process from "man bash" section "Signals". The bash documentation uses "current terminal process group ID" to describe consept that is sometimes just called process group. And when *terminal* receives Ctrl+C it will automatically send SIGINT to all process in the foreground process group. The important part is "If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes." – child cannot prevent delivery of signal, only delay processing.

Comment: It turns out this can be done after all, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65935205/334451

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> sends a signal to the program to tell it to stop. What you want is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> which sends the signal EOT (end of transmission). You will need to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> twice unless you are at the beginning of a line.

```sh
some text<c-d><c-d>
```

or

```sh
some text<return>
<c-d>
```