How to correctly run a Go application with a Makefile on Windows
I am trying to run a Go application on Windows 11 using the following Makefile:
build:
    go build -o ./bin/my-service ./cmd/my-service

cls: build
    cmd /c cls

# Run the application
run: cls
    ./bin/my-service

# Clean build artifacts
clean:
    rmdir /s /q bin


And then I use this command: make run
This works except that in my Go application I have code similar to this:
    // Create a WaitGroup to wait for goroutines to finish
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Create a channel to listen for OS signals (e.g., Ctrl+C)
    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    // Create a context that can be canceled
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    // Start a goroutine that we want to stop gracefully
    wg.Add(1)
    go startGoroutine(ctx, &wg)

    /* THIS WORKS FINE */

    // Block until a signal is received (e.g., Ctrl+C)
    <-sigChan

    cancel()

    // Signal received, handle the graceful shutdown
    fmt.Println("Received shutdown signal, stopping goroutines...")

    // Perform any necessary cleanup, stop goroutines, etc.

    // Wait for the goroutine to finish
    log.Println("waiting for wg.wait")
    wg.Wait()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("Shutdown complete")

The problem is, as soon as I hit ctrl+c, the application just stops immediately and the 10 second sleep is somehow happening in the background and then I see the shutdown complete line being logged after my cursor, instead of basically keeping my program alive until the very last line.
Now after some debugging, I discovered that if I run the app with:
go run main.go
It works as expected
So obviously the issue is with the way I'm using a Makefile.
One thing I have found, is that if I replace the run command in my Makefile with this:
cmd /c start /wait "C:\full_path_to_app\my-service.exe"
Then it works.
But for this to work, I have to specify the .exe in my build command as well as specifying the absolute path to my .exe file.
Also, when I run this from Windows Terminal, it actually now opens a new window instead of running in the same terminal window, which is what happens with 'go run main.go'.
So my question:
Is there a way to have make wait for my program to exit completely when I hit ctrl+c ??

The following answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/65935205/334451

There is no "set -m" equivalent for windows.
